# yocto: do_validate_branches() failure using SRCREV="${AUTOREV}" in a linux-yocto-custom

Tags: linux, git, linux-kernel, yocto, bitbake

I'm setting up yocto v1.7.1 "dizzy" to build a custom Linux image from a customized Linux kernel revision checked into my local git repository.

When going through the build process it fails during `do_validate_branches()` with the following error messages.

```
DEBUG: Executing shell function do_validate_branches
usage: git cat-file (-t|-s|-e|-p|<type>|--textconv) <object>
   or: git cat-file (--batch|--batch-check) < <list_of_objects>

<type> can be one of: blob, tree, commit, tag
    -t                    show object type
    -s                    show object size
    -e                    exit with zero when there's no error
    -p                    pretty-print object's content
    --textconv            for blob objects, run textconv on object's content
    --batch[=<format>]    show info and content of objects fed from the standard input
    --batch-check[=<format>]
                          show info about objects fed from the standard input

ERROR:  is not a valid commit ID.
ERROR: The kernel source tree may be out of sync
WARNING: exit code 1 from a shell command.
ERROR: Function failed: do_validate_branches (log file is located at etc..)
```

Looking at the generated code for do_validate_branches the problem seems to be because it is calling `git cat-file -t ${machine_srcrev}`, but `${machine_srcrev}` is an empty string. Further this seems to be because I am using the following in my **linux-yocto-custom.bb**

```
SRCREV="${AUTOREV}"
```

Because when I replace it with a revision number I no longer get the problem, such as...

```
SRCREV="7035c2a67d964acbb5d917f470bcda42691a3d9c"
```

The thing is I actually want this recipe to build from the HEAD of the branch, so putting a specific revision does not seem to be what I'm after and `SRCREV="${AUTOREV}"` would seem to be what I actually want. But as mentioned above this makes `${SRCREV_machine}` is an empty string, rather than `AUTOINC` as I think it should be evaluating to.

Can anyone offer me any insight on how I can get the recipe to both follow the head without having to constantly update the recipe to contain the correct `SRCREV` and have it pass its `do_validate_branches()`? What am I missing here?

Edit: More info...

The problem also seems to be fixed if I modify my **kernel-yocto.bbclass** as follows... @285

```
-    machine_srcrev="${SRCREV_machine}" 
+    machine_srcrev="${@ get_machine_branch(d, "${SRCREV}" )}"
```

My understanding of my change is I am making it explicitly re-get the `$SRCREV` from my machine branch. Which the original seems to think is already stored in `${SRCREV_machine}`. Though the original results in an empty string and my change results in `AUTOINC`.

Though I still think I must be missing something, because I shouldn't need to be editing the base classes. But I'm always more inclined to think I'm missing something, than that this is a bug. Perhaps I should be posting this to the yocto mailing lists somewhere.

Comment: Not sure if it is necessary for your case, but have you added `SRCPV` to `PV` per http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/1.6/dev-manual/dev-manual.html#platdev-appdev-srcrev ?

Comment: Yep in I have `PV = "${LINUX_VERSION}+git${SRCPV}"` which was included in the original I got from running yocto-bsp create.
This seems to be confirmed by the directory structure made during build which contains a `3.14.28+gitAUTOINC+7035c2a67d-r0` directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some small discussion on the yocto mailing list...
http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.linux.embedded.yocto.general/24316

**Summary:**

It seems that the current logic in `do_validate_branches()` is not full proof.

In particular it seems that `SRCREV_machine` is not set correctly by the time it gets to `do_validate_branches()`, at least in this instance where I am using **linux-yocto-custom.bb** and trying to track the head of a source branch with `SRCREV="${AUTOREV}"`. It is currently being looked at and reworked, hopefully for v1.8 release.

A good work around is to just set `SRCREV_machine` in your **linux-yocto-custom.bb**. In particular you can set it to the same thing as your `SRCREV` variable on the line directly after setting your `SRCREV` variable. So that it looks like...

```
SRCREV="${AUTOREV}"
SRCREV_machine="${AUTOREV}"    # or SRCREV_machine="${SRCREV}"
```

Keeping in mind that eventually when you lock down the source version you are building from and replace `"${AUTOREV}"` with a specific revision, this problem then goes away.

So this work around is only neccesary for development builds when the source you are building from is still progressing, so you want to track the moving head with `"${AUTOREV}"`.